# Android NavigationDrawer does not toggle on click of hamburger icon

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-view

I have a weird situation. Below is a snippet of my main activity code which has a navigation drawer

```
open class MainActivity : BaseActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

var toggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null
var mInstance : MainActivity? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    toggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer_layout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close){}

    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle as DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)
    toggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
    toggle?.syncState()

    val back : Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(back)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    showFragment(LandingFragment())
    logout_layout.setOnClickListener({ logout()})
}
```

**Problem**

The navigation drawer does not open on click of the hamburger icon but the click starts working once the drawer is opened with swipe gesture. What could be the reason. A little guidance will be appreciated.

**Edit**

*Layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_common_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/logout_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_logout"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logout"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the drawer `NavigationView`'s `visibility` set to `gone` or `invisible` in the layout XML?

Comment: can you use **onOptionsItemSelected()** method for menu?

Comment: @MikeM. No I have not added visibility property to the `drawerview`.

Comment: Please post your layout. Btw, I meant the `View` that is the drawer, not the `DrawerLayout`. Looks like a `NavigationView`, in this case.

Comment: @JanviVyas tried that, but no luck

Comment: @MikeM. updated

Comment: Remove `android:visibility="gone"` from the `<NavigationView>`.

Comment: That solved, thanks @MikeM.